# Excel VBA adodb error 3001 using rs.filter

Tags: excel, vba, filter, rs

Using Excel 2013 with Access 2013

Using Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;

After rs.open Table, I wrote an rs.filter with

This is my code

```
myFilter = "sd_am = 'abcd' and sd_h = '' and (sd_k = 'option1' or _ 
     sd_k = 'option2' or sd_k = 'option3') and sd_l = 'kuku'"
rs.filter = myFilter
```

I get error 3001 !
I tried to change the filter with different syntax - doesn't work !

Comment: From [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee275540(v=bts.10).aspx) referring to multiple conditions in a filter: "One restriction on these combinations is that OR clauses can only be used at the highest (major) level of the logical operation."

Answer (score 0):

It appears that rs.filter is a weak function !

Using the same syntax with select - did the job !